# where is the command-line config saved in .csproj?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, config

I'm working on a C# project on Visual Sutio 2015 community. I changed the Properties debug->command-line, Is stored in local machine, bug there are no changes in .csproj file, so I can't push it to git. Where is it? How do I push it to git?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's in the `Foo.csproj.user` file, as that's basically a user-specific setting. (Different users will often want different command line options.) I wouldn't suggest pushing that to git.

Comment: I found it follow your answer.  I used the command-line to control the switch of update when app startup when debug. So I want every one to use it. Thank you!!!